# Changing the default name of chapters and appendixes in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices

I want to add the `part` before number of chapters and add `attachment` before number of appendixes in my table of contents.
I use this code

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{part }
\settowidth{\cftchapnumwidth}{part  20\quad \qquad}
\renewcommand{\cftfigaftersnum}{:}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{one}
\section{one-two}
\appendix
  \chapter{appendix one}
  \chapter{appendix two}

\end{document}
```

and the result is like this:

[image]

How can I change `part` to `attachment` for my appendixes?

Comment: After `\appendix` you can redefine part name: `\renewcommand{\partname}{Attachment}`.

Comment: @Sigur: It's not that easy, since the OP uses `tocloft`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, I see. Sorry.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Don't you know the hard way?:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a line in the `.toc` file just when the command `\appendix` is issued:

```
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\appendix{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftchappresnum}{attachment }}%
}
\makeatother
```

In this way, the `.toc` file will contain a line

```
\renewcommand {\cftchappresnum }{attachment }
```

MWE (I've redefined `\cftchapnumwidth` to fit with the word `attachment`)

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{part }
\settowidth{\cftchapnumwidth}{attachment  20\quad \qquad}
\renewcommand{\cftfigaftersnum}{:}

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\appendix{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftchappresnum}{attachment }}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{one}
\section{one-two}
\appendix
  \chapter{appendix one}
  \chapter{appendix two}

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

If you don't want to use `\g@addto@macro` you can load the `apptools` package and use its `\AtAppendix` command. That is, substitute the above code with

```
\usepackage{apptools}
\AtAppendix{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftchappresnum}{attachment }}%
}
```